# Form that will accept embedded codes from google map

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a html form that will save embedded code from google map to my database but every time I click on submit form and page error happens it looks like my form can't handle the embedded code form google map...
here is google map embedded code looks like

```
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3860.0771496739467!2d121.04721311439732!3d14.651561889770017!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3397b70e3e03cbe9%3A0x56a5e07b59ea8de8!2sQuezon+Memorial+Circle!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sph!4v1513181395201" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: well that would be html is rather risky, just ask them to input the link. (Only the src-value)

Comment: `<input type="url">` And then check if it starts with _https:// www.google.com/maps/embed?_